# Update is updating more rows that it should

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a small table (145 rows) with a client ID column.  I am trying to use this table to determine what rows to update another table that has ~85000 rows.  I only want the matching 145 rows updated.

When I do this query I see all the rows I expect to get updated (missing_names is the 145-row table):

```
SELECT *
FROM MEMBER M
JOIN missing_names MN
ON MN.ID = M.ID
WHERE MN.ID IS NOT NULL
```

I am trying to pull data from a different table and do the update like this:

```
UPDATE MEMBER
SET LastName = R.Client_Last, 
FirstName = R.Client_First, 
Gender = 
FROM Roster R
JOIN missing_names MN
ON MN.ID = R.Client_ID
WHERE MN.ID IS NOT NULL
```

When I run this update statement I see the different IDs with the same first and last name.  The roster table has the correct names for a client ID.  I thought this type of update statement would only update a matching row in the member table from the matching row in the roster table?

Comment: In the update statement's FROM clause you are not referencing MEMBER at all. Why is that? I don't even know what that means. Is that just a cross join?

Comment: That was the answer.  As for why...I am not sure, thought I didn't need it but I actually did.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the update statement's FROM clause you are not referencing MEMBER at all. Why is that? I don't even know what that means. Is that just a cross join?

Turns out that it is. This leads to all rows being updated.